# Increment part of alphanumeric string in OpenOffice Calc

Tags: excel, openoffice.org, openoffice-calc

I have an alphanumeric string (a serial number) like this

S/N:WLD4450001256790

I was trying to increment it with the classic 'drag&drop' method, but it gaves me strange results, eg.

```
S/N:WLD4450001256790
S/N:WLD415138135
S/N:WLD415138136
S/N:WLD415138137
S/N:WLD415138138
S/N:WLD415138139
S/N:WLD415138140
S/N:WLD415138141
S/N:WLD415138142
S/N:WLD415138143
```

I think the problem is due the longness of the number, because when I use an alphanumeric string with a lower number it works:

Example:

```
S/N:WLD445000
S/N:WLD445001
S/N:WLD445002
S/N:WLD445003
S/N:WLD445004
S/N:WLD445005
S/N:WLD445006
```

Let's go back to the first alphanumerical string

```
S/N:WLD4450001256790
```

Everything but the last 6 numbers is a costant. The only 'incremental' part is 256790. 
I'm trying to find a way to create a macro or something where the first part of the alphanumerical string is just a ... 'string' (S/N:WLD4450001) and the rest is a number, hoping to succeed in incrementing it.

Anyone can give a me an advice for that? 
I'm pretty new in excel, and i'm reading about macros in these days.

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cases like this I like to simplify the problem: I will put the string in column A and the incremental number in column B and the concatenation of the two strings in column C. The operator for the concatenation is `&`, so:

- Type `S/N:WLD415` in `A1`
- Type a number in `B1`
- Type `=A1&B1` in `C1`
- Select `A1:A10` and press `Ctrl + D` to copy the constant string
- Select `A2` and drag the little square on the bottom right of the cell down while pressing the `Ctrl` key to copy and increment (fill series)
- Use one of the two ways described above to copy the formula down

[image]

Comment: Excellent solution and not row-restricted. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

In **A1** enter:

```
="S/N:WLD445000" & 1256790+(ROW()-1)
```

and copy down.

[image]